# Необходимо создать плавный переход с одной страницы на другую

Tags: javascript, jquery

Надо чтобы переход был плавным как вот тут: http://kerrigan.su/koshkin/
Когда одна страница начинает исчезать - вторая одновременно начинает появляться.
Есть стандартный скрипт для плавного перехода:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").css("display", "none"); 
$("body").fadeIn(500); 
$("a.fade").click(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();
linkLocation = this.href;
$("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage); 
});
function redirectPage() {
window.location = linkLocation;
}
});
</script>
```

Но в этом скрипте появление новой страницы начинается только после полного исчезновения старой. Очень грубо выглядит. Между страницами белый фон мелькает. Как изменить скрипт, чтобы исчезание первой страницы шло одновременно с появлением второй ?

Comment: @EvaKerrigan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

На сайте скорей всего идет наложение DIVов через `z-index` с `position absolute`.

Ваша задача - через CSS свойство opacity постепенно уменьшать прозрачность одного дива, и увеличивать прозрачность нужного. Затем, по достижении opacity:0 скрываемого дива присвоить ему значение display:none.

2 варианта:

1. Прописать в CSS свойства "transition: all 1s ease-out!important"(или easyIn) и скрытие дива делать просто с зарежкой `delay()` или `SetTimeOut`.
2. Попробовать менять `opacity` методом `.animate(время, function(){})`(сам не пробовал, не могу сказать). в функции пропишите изменение css display.

Answer (score 0):

Меняя window.location, вы перезагружаете страницы, на приведенном вами сайте этого нет, равно как и вообще какой-либо дополнительной загрузки. Пример использует библиотеку [jshowoff](http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/), просто элементы управления вынесены в центр.

Comment: Да, я знаю про jshowoff. Я этот сайт и сделала. Но я его сделала сайт внутри слайдера. А когда стала пытаться вставлять картинки вместо кнопок, чтобы тени были нарисованные и вставлять дубль-гис виджет карту - оказалось это невозможным внутри слайдера. И я переделала этот сайт http://kerrigan.su/koshkin/ просто под сайт без слайдера, с обычными 4-мя страницами и кнопками http://kerrigan.su/koshkinneslide/. На нем все работает. И картинки вместо кнопок, и виджет дубль гис... Но заказчику принципиально чтобы остался этот эффект плавной смены страниц.